# Unable to compile clean maven generated project template for richfaces simpleapp

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, richfaces

These are my first steps with RichFaces and Maven. I've stuck on the error after I generated a project template using Eclipse / Maven. I will appreciate any help resolving this error:

> Failure to transfer xpp3:xpp3_min:pom:1.1.4c from
>   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository,
>   resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of
>   central has elapsed or updates are forced.
>
> Original error: Could not transfer artifact xpp3:xpp3_min:pom:1.1.4c
>   from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): The operation was
>   cancelled.    pom.xml /RFproj1    line 1  Maven Configuration Problem

I am using Eclipse 3.7 with Maven 3.0.3. The project name is RFproj1 and i generated it as:
[Eclipse] File-> New -> Other -> Maven -> Maven project etc. I am pasting also a beginning of the pom.xml, where the error's icon stick to the line 1.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ksz</groupId>
    <artifactId>RFproj1</artifactId>
    <name>RichFaces 4 Application</name>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <url>http://jboss.org/richfaces</url>
```

Is the problem with local repository? Should I clean it somehow? Or should I enforce any updates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove your local repository on the hard drive and try to build a second time ...best on command line via mvn clean package....

Comment: By 'local repository' do You mean $HOME/.m2 directory?

Comment: Yes...but not the entire you can delete only parts of it...for example org/apache ...